# MySQL Trigger After Deleted Update not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i'm sorry for making this question again since there is so much in the forum about this. but i hope my problem is different from others. and sorry for my bad english.

First i have 2 Table (parent and child)
Parent (Location)

| loc_id | loc_size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 75 |

Child (Area)

| ar_id | ar_loc_id | ar_size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 35 |
| 2 | 2 | 40 |

this is my after delete trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_area_location
AFTER DELETE
   ON area FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE location SET loc_size = loc_size + old.ar_size WHERE loc_id=old.ar_loc_id

END;
```

example, if i want to delete ar_id = '2' then the ar_size will be updated in the location loc_size.

since loc_size value is '0' then the value will be 40 after the trigger running.

the problem is the trigger is not running correctlly, the loc_size not updating at all just '0' value after the trigger running.

what i'm missing or what happen since its not working at all.

please kindly to help me fix this issue.
Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: Please publish delete trigger in full together with example delete statement. BTW discussion about insert an update triggers is a pointless distraction..

Comment: done, updated and throw the distraction

Comment: The published query is syntactically incorrect in that it is missing a terminator on the update statement - something that any ide would tell you ,and you may need to set delimiters..

Comment: Thank You @P.Salmon for Your information about delimeters. But thats not the issue in my query. since it running well but no result to recieve the value from old.ar_size into loc_size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem in your trigger. I tested it and it is working. To make it complete, I added the insert trigger on table `area`.

```
create table location(loc_id int,loc_size int);
create table area(ar_id int,ar_loc_id int,ar_size int);


delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_area_location
AFTER insert
   ON area FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE location SET loc_size = loc_size - new.ar_size WHERE loc_id=new.ar_loc_id;

-- Note: In reality, you should throw in an if statement before the UPDATE to make sure there is enough loca_size to be taken away by the ar_size.
END//


CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_area_location
AFTER DELETE
   ON area FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE location SET loc_size = loc_size + old.ar_size WHERE loc_id=old.ar_loc_id;

END//
delimiter ;

insert into location values(1,100),(2,75);

select * from location;
+--------+----------+
| loc_id | loc_size |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |      100 |
|      2 |       75 |
+--------+----------+

select * from area;
Empty set (0.00 sec)


-- Test the insert
insert into area values(1,2,35),(2,2,40);
select * from area;
+-------+-----------+---------+
| ar_id | ar_loc_id | ar_size |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     1 |         2 |      35 |
|     2 |         2 |      40 |
+-------+-----------+---------+

 select * from location;
+--------+----------+
| loc_id | loc_size |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |      100 |
|      2 |        0 |
+--------+----------+

-- test the delete
delete from area where ar_id=2;

select * from area;
+-------+-----------+---------+
| ar_id | ar_loc_id | ar_size |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     1 |         2 |      35 |
+-------+-----------+---------+

select * from location;
+--------+----------+
| loc_id | loc_size |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |      100 |
|      2 |       40 |
+--------+----------+
```

As you can see, in both the insert and delete operations, the values have been updated accordingly .
-- **UPDATED FROM HERE** -- 

Here is an amped-up version of trigger `after_insert_area_location`, in which I shall demonstrate the newly added IF statement to retain data integrity. Note, the `SIGNAL` statment is used to raise an error which serves as a warning message as well as terminates the operation.

```
-- First of all, I truncated my table so we can start from scratch.
-- Make sure the original trigger is dropped before creating the newer one to avoid conflicts.

drop trigger after_insert_area_location //
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_area_location
AFTER insert
   ON area FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
if (select loc_size from location where loc_id=new.ar_loc_id) - new.ar_size < 0 then
signal sqlstate '77777' set message_text='You cannot take more land than you have'; -- Note: the sqlstate code and the message_text can be modified to your liking
end if;
UPDATE location SET loc_size = loc_size - new.ar_size WHERE loc_id=new.ar_loc_id;

END//

delimiter ;

-- then let's populate the location table:
insert into location values(1,100),(2,75);

select * from location;
+--------+----------+
| loc_id | loc_size |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |      100 |
|      2 |       75 |
+--------+----------+

select * from area;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

-- Now we test the insert one row at a time:
 insert into area values(1,2,35);

 select * from location;
+--------+----------+
| loc_id | loc_size |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |      100 |
|      2 |       40 |
+--------+----------+

 select * from area;
+-------+-----------+---------+
| ar_id | ar_loc_id | ar_size |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     1 |         2 |      35 |
+-------+-----------+---------+

-- now we add another row with an ar_size more than its location can afford:

insert into area values(2,2,80);
ERROR 1644 (77777): You cannot take more land than you have
```

As you see , an error is raised by the `SIGNAL` statement in the trigger's `IF` statement with the SQL_STATE code `77777` and the message which are preset. This revokes the changes made since the insert of the new row.

```
 select * from location;
+--------+----------+
| loc_id | loc_size |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |      100 |
|      2 |       40 |
+--------+----------+

select * from area;
+-------+-----------+---------+
| ar_id | ar_loc_id | ar_size |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     1 |         2 |      35 |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

To put it in a nutshell, we can use an IF statement in a trigger to exercise some control over the flow of data. And the `SIGNAL` statement can be used to deliberately invoke an error to stop/undo the execution of the trigger as well as the operation that initiated the trigger. As denoted above, not only the `UPDATE` in the trigger didn't get executed, the `insert` statement which evoked the trigger has also been undone.

Comment: Thank You @blabla_bingo, Your Answer is correct. but for me it doesn't work. the code is also the same as You make (Insert and delete)

returning/update the value in location where col loc_size didn't recieve the value from old.ar_size. i don't know the error since there is no error in the log because it running well no error at all.

with the note that You gave me, i didn't do it, because i don't know the if statement can work inside trigger.
can You help me with the note You mention above. many thanks

Comment: @me.theblackz Check the update made for you.

Comment: Thank You so much for the if statement. I've never thought that it can be done like that. many thanks for the knowledge.

so if I enter the if statement in the after delete which contain like this 

`if (select ar_size from area where ar_loc_id=old.loc_id) = 0
then
update location set loc_size=loc_size+old.ar_size where loc_id=old.ar_loc_id endif;`

can it be done like that in the after delete?
just checking if its not 0 in ar_size then it must send the value until it zero.

any suggestion on this?

Comment: I would cater for the possibility of nulls in both terms by coalescing to 0..

Comment: @me.theblackz this statement `if (select ar_size from area where ar_loc_id=old.loc_id) = 0 then update location set loc_size=loc_size+old.ar_size where loc_id=old.ar_loc_id endif; ` is confusing, as you have both old.loc_id and old.ar_size, which are mutually exclusive as you can only use the keywords `old` and `new` for the columns in the triggered table.

Comment: many thanks @blabla_bingo.. and sorry for slow respond.. i've been so busy with others. so right now, i'm doing a new mysql since it doesn't work. created new database and tables and it works like magic. don't know the problems is.